# Js: create html element that inherits from some js class

Tags: javascript, html

I have js class (if js supports classes is offtopic for this question):

```
var MyClass=function(){
....
}

MyClass.prototype.someMethod=function(){
...
}
```

I want to create html element (for example div) that will inherit MyClass. For example for custom elements I could use the following:

```
  var SimpleTableClass = document.registerElement('simple-table',{prototype: new MyClass()});
  simpleTable=new SimpleTableClass();
```

The only idea I have is:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.prototype=new MyClass();
```

But I don't know if it's safe method, because I will override all html element prototype.

If it's possible I'd like to get not only html element but and its constructor (class) as in example with SimpleTableClass.

Comment: There was a library 5 years ago called PrototypeJS. It was extending native elements prototypes. You can do the same, although it not recommended: `HTMLDivElement.prototype.someMethod = function() {...}`.

Comment: To some extent this question is reminiscent of what the [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) project is all about.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you for your time. Did developers of Polymer solve the problem I've posted?

Comment: Well Polymer is a fairly ambitious project that intends to make it possible to create custom HTML elements or "widgets". Part of that is making it possible to have custom behavior. [You can read more about it at the project website.](https://www.polymer-project.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only idea I have is:
>
> ```
> var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
> newDiv.prototype=new MyClass();
> ```
>
> But I don't know if it's safe method, because I will override all html element prototype.

More importantly than whether it's safe, it's pointless. :-) It creates a `prototype` property on the `div`, which does nothing to give it any methods from the `MyClass` instance.

You could extend the element with all of the methods from `MyClass.prototype` (or from an instance of `MyClass`) by copying their references to the element. Many libraries provide a function typically called `extend` that does exactly that. ([Here's jQuery's](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend), [here's Underscore's](http://underscorejs.org/#extend).) This is usually called a "mixin." There's no inheritance there, you're just grabbing the references. It's safe enough other than the usual warnings about naming conflicts on expando properties. To minimize the odds of naming conflicts, you could prefix your methods with some, well, prefix.

For instance:

```js
var MyStuff = {
  myDoThis: function() {
    // ...
  },
  myTurnGreen: function() {
    this.style.color = "green";
  }
  // ...and so on...
};

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "This is the text of my div";
document.body.appendChild(div);
Object.keys(MyStuff).forEach(function(key) {
  div[key] = MyStuff[key];
});
setTimeout(function() {
  div.myTurnGreen();
}, 500);
```